# how do I get more repeat business from existing clients?

Tags: working-from-home

I'd like to get more repeat business from clients.  Aside from asking them "are you looking for any more work done" is there any other way to approach them to secure more work?

Comment: This really depends on *what* you do. In most businesses there are satellite services.. You came to me for A, but you may also be interested B, C, and D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upselling (the term for getting more work from existing clients) starts with asking clients if you can help them with anything else. However, often your added value as a freelancer, external to the company, is that you can also provide some advice or offer new tech that the client is not aware of.
Maybe a client doesn't know he needs X or Y. A few things you can try:

1. create a newsletter to existing or previous clients detailing new projects or new features you have created, that might trigger an 'old' client to want that as well
2. Directly approach a client with advice or a concrete offer: "For client A I have done X, I think this might be beneficial for you as well, can I interest you in X?"
3. Actively search out innovative ideas or features competitors have and point this out to your client, often a competitor move is just the thing to get a client interested in an additional feature or project

Comment: The answer is pretty straightforward.  The ideas you outlined are intuitive.  I was hoping to find a new idea.  Perhaps the newsletter idea is something I could use.  The problem of not having a wide client base is that when you do the things you outlined and the client says 'no thanks' how do you continue.  Thinking now more about my own question I think the crux of the matter is that it's all about sales.  You have to be a good salesman and some of  us who lack that trait need to do something else.  I guess there's no replacement for good sales skills.